# C++ compiler unable to create temporary files for rstan?

Tags: r, rstan, rtools

I am installing rstan for R 4.3.1.

In preparation In installed RTools43, which appears to be functioning correctly:

```
> Sys.which("make")
                                        make 
"C:\\PROGRA~1\\rtools43\\usr\\bin\\make.exe"
```

rstan also was installed without apparent issue:

```
> install.packages("rstan")

trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/4.3/rstan_2.21.8.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 3352608 bytes (3.2 MB)
downloaded 3.2 MB

package ‘rstan’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
```

The problem arises when I preform the example model for rstan:

```
> example(stan_model, package = "rstan", run.dontrun = TRUE)
```

A long string of information rolls out describing the test, however at the end it stops with an error 127:

```
Compilation ERROR, function(s)/method(s) not created!
Error in compileCode(f, code, language = language, verbose = verbose) : 
  using C++ compiler: 'g++.exe (GCC) 12.2.0'using C++14Cannot create temporary file in D:\R\R-4.2.3\: No such file or directorymake: *** [C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-4.3.1/etc/x64/Makeconf:272: file7568219137a8.o] Error 127
>
```

I do not understand why it is trying to create temporary files in my D drive when everything (R and RTools) is installed on my C drive? Please let me know if you can identify any avenues for figuring out a solution.

Thanks you for your time!

UPDATE-I have added the commands requested by br00t:

```
> Sys.getenv("PATH")
[1] "C:\\Program Files\\rtools43/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/bin;
     C:\\Program Files\\rtools43/usr/bin;\\usr\\bin;

> Sys.getenv("BINPREF") 
[1] ""

> readLines("~/.Rprofile")
Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(con, "r") :
  cannot open file 'C:\Users\userA\Documents/.Rprofile': No such file or directory

> readLines("~/.Renviron")
[1] "TMP = 'D:/R/R-4.2.3"             "PATH=\"${RTOOLS40_HOME}\\usr\\bin;${PATH}\""

> devtools::session_info("rstan")
Error in loadNamespace(x) : there is no package called ‘devtools’
```

Rprofile and devtools are concerning. For reference I installed this version of R after uninstalling a past edition and deleting all related library directories.

I have also had similar problems with getting cmdstanr to work.

Comment: Please post the output from:

```r
Sys.getenv("PATH")
Sys.getenv("BINPREF")
readLines("~/.Rprofile")
readLines("~/.Renviron")
devtools::session_info("rstan")
```

Comment: You may also want to consider using cmdstanr (https://github.com/stan-dev/cmdstanr)?